# How to filter specific attribute from array and store into variable

Tags: javascript, arrays, data-structures

I have an array of data as follows:

```
var arr = [{
    "Sports" : "Hockey",
    "Country" : "AUS",
    "Players" : 11
},{
    "Sports" : "Football",
    "Country" : "Eng",
    "Players" : 11
},{
    "Sports" : "Tennis",
    "Country" : "AUS",
    "Players" : 11
},{
    "Sports" : "Cricket",
    "Country" : "Ind",
    "Players" : 11
},{
    "Sports" : "Gymnastic",
    "Country" : "Russia",
    "Players" : 11
},{
    "Sports" : "Gym",
    "Country" : "AUS",
    "Players" : 11
}];
```

I want to create an array of objects where I want to use only uniqe data of countries from my array above. In this, case I shoud get something like:

```
var country = [
    { AUS: "" },
    { Eng :"" },
    { Ind : "" },
    { Russia :"" }
];
```

And then I can add my own attrbuites like `capital`:

```
var country = [{
    AUS: "",
    capital : "Canbara"
}, {
    Eng :"",
    capital : "London"
}, {
    Ind : "",
    capital : "Delhi"
}, {
    Russia :"",
    capital : "Masco"
}];
```

Can anybody help me with how to achive this?

This is what I have tried so far:

```
var result = [];
array.forEach(function(e) {
    result.push(this[e.Country]);
}, {});
```

I am getting stuck here.

Comment: How are you going to use the result array? I think that an object `{ Ind: 'Delhi' }` might be better.

Comment: Why do you want the key in your `country` array of object to be the country name? Wouldn't it be better to have a consistant key like `name` and the value would be the country name?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `map` method which accepts a **callback** provided function.

Also, use `Set` `ES6` **feature** in order to remove **duplicates**.

The `Set` object lets you store `unique` values of any type, whether `primitive` values or `object` **references**.

```js
var arr = [{ "Sports" : "Hockey", "Country" : "AUS", "Players" : 11 },{ "Sports" : "Football", "Country" : "Eng", "Players" : 11 },{ "Sports" : "Tennis", "Country" : "AUS", "Players" : 11 },{ "Sports" : "Cricket", "Country" : "Ind", "Players" : 11 },{ "Sports" : "Gymnastic", "Country" : "Russia", "Players" : 11 },{ "Sports" : "Gym", "Country" : "AUS", "Players" : 11 }];
arr=[...new Set(arr.map(function(item){
  return item.Country;
}))].map(function(item){
  return {[item]:""};
});
console.log(arr);
```

Another solution is to use `arrow` functions.

```js
var arr = [{ "Sports" : "Hockey", "Country" : "AUS", "Players" : 11 },{ "Sports" : "Football", "Country" : "Eng", "Players" : 11 },{ "Sports" : "Tennis", "Country" : "AUS", "Players" : 11 },{ "Sports" : "Cricket", "Country" : "Ind", "Players" : 11 },{ "Sports" : "Gymnastic", "Country" : "Russia", "Players" : 11 },{ "Sports" : "Gym", "Country" : "AUS", "Players" : 11 }];
arr=[...new Set(arr.map(a => a.Country))].map(a=> ({[a] : ""}));
console.log(arr);
```

Comment: Thanks for answer but in this case, `AUS` is repeating. I want only uniqe. (Non repeating)

Comment: @David, have a look now.

Comment: Thanks, let me try this.

Comment: Since you given two answer. Thanks, Is it possible to place all uniqe country in to just into array. like arr2 = [AUS,IND,ENG,RASSIA]

Comment: @David, yes, just use `arr=[...new Set(arr.map(a => a.Country))]`

Comment: Yes, I got it. Thanks a ton :)

Answer (score 2):

It would be better to use object instead of array for storing the result (that would allow you to skip duplicates automatically):

```
const result = {};

array.forEach(o => {
    result[o.Country] = {
        [o.Country]: '',
        capital: '',
    };
});
```

This will return something like:

```
{
    AUS: {AUS: "", capital: ""},
    Eng: {Eng: "", capital: ""},
    Ind: {Ind: "", capital: ""},
    Russia: {Russia: "", capital: ""}
}
```

It depends on how you really want to use the result.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Set` to remove duplicates and then again `map()` to get objects.

```js
var arr = [{"Sports":"Hockey","Country":"AUS","Players":11},{"Sports":"Football","Country":"Eng","Players":11},{"Sports":"Tennis","Country":"AUS","Players":11},{"Sports":"Cricket","Country":"Ind","Players":11},{"Sports":"Gymnastic","Country":"Russia","Players":11},{"Sports":"Gym","Country":"AUS","Players":11}]

var r = [...new Set(arr.map(({Country}) => Country))].map(e => ({[e]: ''}))
console.log(r)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do

```js
var arr = [{
    "Sports" : "Hockey",
    "Country" : "AUS",
    "Players" : 11
},{
    "Sports" : "Football",
    "Country" : "Eng",
    "Players" : 11
},{
    "Sports" : "Tennis",
    "Country" : "AUS",
    "Players" : 11
},{
    "Sports" : "Cricket",
    "Country" : "Ind",
    "Players" : 11
},{
    "Sports" : "Gymnastic",
    "Country" : "Russia",
    "Players" : 11
},{
    "Sports" : "Gym",
    "Country" : "AUS",
    "Players" : 11
}];

let result = arr.map(e => e.Country);
result = result.filter((e, i) => result.indexOf(e) == i).reduce((a, b) => {
    let obj = {};
    obj[b] = "";
    a.push(obj);
    return a;
}, []);;
console.log(result);
```